# Facebook login for Django and url redirection?

Tags: javascript, python, django, facebook

I have implemented a Django app having a user login/registration page. I wanted to make facebook user id's also possible for logging into my app. In doing so, i followed this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login . With the help of that link i can now login using the Facebook id also. Clicking on the facebook login button, pop ups with a facebook login page; giving the username n passw, makes it logged in with facebook. But after logging in also the page is redirected back to my home page. I need to redirect it to some other url, say http://localhost/login/ . Can somebody help me to solve this. I will paste my html part used for django login.

**html**

```
<body>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'114322105313139', cookie:true,
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>


  <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>

</body>
```

**settings.py**

```
# Django settings for universityDB project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'student',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'qburst',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}


EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "rv@gmail.com" #create a gmail id
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "xxxx"#pwd for that id
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 


FACEBOOK_CACHE_TIMEOUT=1800
FACEBOOK_APP_ID='xxx'
FACEBOOK_API_KEY='xxx'
FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY='xxxx'
FACEBOOK_INTERNAL = 'TRUE'


# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'b_3=te)1b57mqsz^))jg95i%umw=*pug_i*8j!$6@y4(ie=8x$'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'facebook.djangofb.FacebookMiddleware',
    'facebookconnect.middleware.FacebookConnectMiddleware',
   # 'facebook.djangofb.FacebookMiddleware',
   # 'socialregistration.middleware.FacebookMiddleware' ,    

)


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'facebookconnect.models.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)



LOGIN_URL          = '/login-form/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/logged-in/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL    = '/login-error/'

SOCIAL_AUTH_ERROR_KEY = 'social_errors'

SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'associate_complete'

SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'

SOCIAL_AUTH_EXTRA_DATA = False

SOCIAL_AUTH_EXPIRATION = 'expires'

SOCIAL_AUTH_SESSION_EXPIRATION = False


DUMMY_FACEBOOK_INFO = {
    'uid':0,
    'name':'(Private)',
    'first_name':'(Private)',
    'pic_square_with_logo':'http://www.facebook.com/pics/t_silhouette.gif',
    'affiliations':None,
    'status':None,
    'proxied_email':None,
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'universityDB.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/home/Desktop/universityDB/templates"             
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'universityDetails',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'captcha',
    'facebookconnect',
    'social_auth',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code just looks like FB's HTML.  You'd need to give us a better idea of your Django Auth structure if you wanted more help.

There are quite a few more steps ahead of you.  I would look into [Django-SocialAuth](https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth) for an easily integrated experience if I were you.

Edit: 
As a follow up to the inclusion of your Settings.py, assuming that you've read the [Facebook Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) docs as well as the SocialAuth README, you will need to set up the appropriate controller for fb's authentication callback url.

After that, hook these SocialAuth views into your current authentication process:

```
def facebook_login(request):
    """
    Facebook login page
    """
    if request.REQUEST.get("device"):
        device = request.REQUEST.get("device")
    else:
        device = "user-agent"

    params = {}
    params["client_id"] = FACEBOOK_APP_ID
    params["redirect_uri"] = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("socialauth_facebook_login_done"))

    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"+urllib.urlencode(params)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

def facebook_login_done(request):
    user = authenticate(request=request)

    if not user:
        request.COOKIES.pop(FACEBOOK_API_KEY + '_session_key', None)
        request.COOKIES.pop(FACEBOOK_API_KEY + '_user', None)

        # TODO: maybe the project has its own login page?
        logging.debug("SOCIALAUTH: Couldn't authenticate user with Django, redirecting to Login page")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('socialauth_login_page'))

    login(request, user)

    logging.debug("SOCIALAUTH: Successfully logged in with Facebook!")

    if request.GET.get('next'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

Comment: i have added my settings.py also. Can u check that now ?

Comment: Can you share the settings.py also.